# vscode lldb and -static-libstdc++

Tags: c++, lldb, vscode-debugger

Ok, I have this strange bug, or behavior I don't understand. If I use `-static-libstdc++` link flag in my project, LLDB fails to show underlying type of a pointer. So here is small example. I have the very basic test executable, with only one main.cpp file:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <memory>

class TestBase
{
public:
    TestBase() = default;
    virtual ~TestBase() = default;

    int m_baseInt = 10;
};

class TestDerived : public TestBase
{
public:
    TestDerived() = default;
    virtual ~TestDerived() override = default;

    int m_derivedInt = 20;
};

int main(int,char*[])
{
    std::unique_ptr<TestBase> regularBase = std::make_unique<TestBase>();
    std::unique_ptr<TestBase> hiddentBase = std::make_unique<TestDerived>();

    TestBase*volatile base = hiddentBase.get();

    volatile int breakpoint = 10;
    ++breakpoint;
}
```

and one CMake file to build it

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(quick-test VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX C)
add_executable(test-exe "main.cpp")
```

For ide I use vscode with CodeLLDB module, and so if you look at 'base' variable it will show TestDerived class (as it should):
[image]

But with only one chage, by adding `-static-libstdc++` link option to my test executable

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(quick-test VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX C)
add_executable(test-exe "main.cpp")
target_link_options(test-exe PRIVATE -static-libstdc++)
```

now lldb is incapable to deduce underlying type of a 'base' pointer:
[image]

For compilation I used clang 14.0.0 and gcc 11.2.0, but it didn't make any difference.
Why does linking statically c++ std lib causes this, and is there any solution for this accept removing this flag?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When linking stdlibc++ statically with clang, lldb shows correct type of the pointer. Did you specify `-g` when building `main.cpp`? Does your shared library has debug symbols? `objdump --syms /usr/lib/libstdc++.so | grep debug` Does your static library has debug symbols? `objdump --syms /usr/lib/libstdc++.a | grep debug`

Comment: Ok, so first of all, I didn't have '-g' option, but it didn't change anything when I added it right now.

Comment: I've tried to check debug symbols for libstd, but there is no libstd in /usr/lib. The only libs I found (which make any sense) were these:
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libstdc++.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30
From those libraries all of shared ones doesn't have any debug symbols, but /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libstdc++.a have.

Comment: And the biggest problem here, that it isn't even a good example as I found out. The executable I provided in my question, was, what I thought, an example of reproducible behavior. The full story is next:

Comment: I'm trying to write module in c++ for godot, and I found that my debugger (lldb) wasn't able to deduce underlying type of pointers. I've tried to compose an simple executable as an example for this question, and started to test all compile/link options used in godot exe, to see what could cause the problem. I thought that libstd was the case, because it did make a change in my test project, but if I remove static linking of libstd from godot, nothing changes, the debugger still not able to see underlying types.. So I basically back to square one, and whole question could be thrown into bin..